# Raspberry Pi escape character

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, autostart

I am trying to create a shell script in which I automatically run a video fullscreen.
It has no way to quit unless I shut down the Raspberry Pi.

What is a small script I can use to bind something like "!" to quit the application?

Comment: How do you run the video? I assume you start a certain video player? If so, maybe that player has documentation about which key to use to exit full screen mode.

Answer (score 0):

I searched Google for 'omxplayer exit fullscreen' and found this answer, originally [posted by **dom**](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=12158&p=131318&hilit=Fbset%20omxplayer#p131318) on the RaspberryPi forum:

> Changing TV modes does lose any content on them (e.g. the console
>   framebuffer).
>
> You can provoke the console framebuffer to be recreated with: fbset
>   -depth 8 && fbset -depth 16
>
> Add that to the end of a script that launches omxplayer.
>
> (for extra points read the depth before launching omxplayer and set it
>   back to original value afterwards)

You might also want to check this [issue report on omxplayer's GitHub](https://github.com/huceke/omxplayer/issues/44).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will work but potentially you could use a tkinter window that you make non visable.

```
#import the tkinter module for the GUI and input control
try:
    # for Python2
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import *
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *

def key(event):
#create a function to control closing the window in this case
    if event.keysym == 'Escape':
        #this currently closes the window however you could add to root.destroy() with
        #the relevant command for closing the video. 
        root.destroy()

#initiate root window, remove it from view, bind all keys (you could just    
#bind '<Escape>' if preffered 
root = Tk.tk
root.withdraW()
root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
```

i am aware this isnt a specific design to your problem however it will let you bind the escape key like you wished. this stopped the whole application in my example however you may have to include extra lines to ensure each part of your application is correctly ended.